# How to add a custom form template in Ninja Forms on Dashboard Page?

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I want to create a new form not by adding a new custom templates such as Contact Us, Event Registration, etc

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?

Comment: Yes I did it by adding few changes using some hooks and some custom code into the Ninja form plugin. Now its working fine as per my need but it took so much time.

I added a checkbox(isTemplate) custom field on Ninja Form add/edit page. If checkbox is checked I am creating/updating a form template file into the template folder of the ninja form when forms submit using ninja form hook. After it I saved file name into the table.

We can display our custom template file by using 'ninja_forms_new_form_templates' hook.